# Including a literal block inside an admonition

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm an RST newbie. I want to create a Warning block that includes a line of code.

Here are four attempts:

```
.. WARNING:: Base case - This doesn't format the next line as a literal::
   $ ls /

.. WARNING:: Split over two lines - This still doesn't format the next line
   as a literal::
   $ ls /

.. WARNING:: Indented - Still no luck::
     $ ls /

.. WARNING:: Split line AND indented. Works, but gives a warning "Unexpected
   indentation"::
     $ ls /
```

And here is the result from Sphinx.

[image: Output from Sphinx]

The last example gives the output I am looking for, but I get a warning from Sphinx when it runs it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I worked it out.</strike> Shortly after posting, I randomly hit on an answer through hitting arbitrary buttons until it worked:

```
.. WARNING:: The magic incantation - a blank line::

   $ ls /
```